What is the right way to reapply a patch?
I've created a patch with a bunch of redirects for the htaccess file. The workflow is as follows.

I apply changes to htaccess, save it.
Then I git diff > patches/htaccess.patch
Then I commit and push changes.

My composer.json contains a script
    "scripts": {
        "post-drupal-scaffold-cmd": [
            "patch -p1 < patches/htaccess.patch"
        ]
    }

Everything works when I apply this patch for the first time. However, if I change and save htaccess again and git diff and commit with the same commands listed above, thinking that this updated patch would just be reapplied, I receive the following message:
> patch -p1 < patches/htaccess.patch
patching file patches/htaccess.patch
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]

If I type n (assuming that I don't want to reverse I just want to reapply) I get
Apply anyway? [n]

Makes sense. I type y, and then I get an error
Hunk #1 FAILED at 1.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file patches/htaccess.patch.rej
patching file web/.htaccess
Hunk #1 FAILED at 157.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file web/.htaccess.rej
Script patch -p1 < patches/htaccess.patch handling the post-drupal-scaffold-cmd event returned with error code 1

I'm obviously missing something with updating my patch.

You need to git diff from the original htaccess every time not from just the one from the last time with other existing changes already in it

@leymannx well, that's what I do if I understand you correctly. Each time I add more redirects to htaccess, I save, I git diff, I commit. The only way the patch works is if I revert htaccess back to original state and then make one single patch. Updating the patch with new redirects brings described errors

The only way the patch works is if I revert htaccess back to original state and then make one single patch. That's what @leymannx is (correctly) saying that you'll need to do. When scaffold downloads .htaccess, it's not the same as the version which you're creating your most recent patch from, so the patch doesn't apply to it. You need to get a fresh .htaccess each time, make all the changes, generate a patch from that, then apply it. In short, the patch must always apply to the original (or more accurately stable) .htaccess, not to the incrementally updated version which exists in your repo

Appreciate your help. The patch is applied without errors now, though I have these many steps. First I require the drupal/core, commit the original htaccess, then add my changes, save, git diff and commit again.
